# Adobe InDesign: Applying a drop shadow to a placed PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, drop-shadow

I am trying to apply a drop shadow to a `PDF` I have placed in my InDesign document. However, when doing so a drop shadow seems to be applied to every element inside the placed `PDF` instead of to the the object itself. See the `.gif` below as a reference for what I'm describing. How do I apply the shadow so that it sits behind the `PDF`?

[image: Drop Shadow Issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a `[paper]` background to the object and it will do the drop shadow around the whole object instead.